# Linq - Conditional where clause gives error

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq

I have a query like below

```
bool isAdmin = true;
var result= (from a in context.VIEW_NAME
                            where a.TYPE== (isAdmin ? (a.TYPE) : "Normal")
                            select new ClassName
                            {
                                .
                                .
                                .


                            });
```

But this gives me an error. `ORA-12704: character set mismatch`

I am using `Oracle` as backend and EF from server side.

Note 1: If I change the query like below it will work

```
 var result= (from a in context.VIEW_NAME
                                where a.TYPE== (isAdmin ? ("SomeString") : "Normal")
                                select new ClassName
                                {
                                    .
                                    .
                                    .


                                });
```

Note 2 : I have tried to to run the below query directly from `PL/SQL` that is also working fine

```
select * from PTR_PNN.PNNHP_COMM_VW  where USR_TYPE=USR_TYPE
```

Any idea why this `character set mismatch` error is coming?

Comment: You can get EF generated SQL and run it to see what's wrong. It has to be something related to `varchar2` / `nvarchar2`. Meanwhile you could change the LINQ query to `where (isAdmin || a.TYPE == "Normal")` which presumably will fix that particular problem.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the point , I am also looking into the same point, in my case I have few empty string there in the table i guess that is what making the issue.

Comment: @IvanStoev where (isAdmin || a.TYPE == "Normal") this is what the line i was looking for. Make it as an answer I can approve it . Thanks man

Comment: You are welcome. I knew that this probably will solve it, but I had no idea what's the problem with your code, which in theory should also work. Probably some Oracle bug. Hence don't feel comfortable to provide it as "answer". But glad it helped you :) Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you. I have checked the datatype , its nvarchar2 in the database , only the thing which might leads to an issue is I have few empty values in the column but in fact it shouldn't throw this error . May be bug in ODAC . Anyway thanks for the alternative